# Sorting A Doubly Linked List with Bubble Sort and a Swap Method

Tags: java, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to sort a self-implemented doubly-linked list however it seems to iterate endlessly and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```java
    public void sortLine() {
     Module current = this.getLeftMostModule();
     Module next = this.getLeftMostModule().getRight();
     while(next != this.getRightMostModule()) {
         while(next != null) {
             if(current.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(next.getName()) > 0) {
                 swap(current, next);
             }
             next = next.getRight();
         }
         current = current.getRight();
     }
    }
    public void swap(Module current, Module next) {
        boolean isLeft = false;
        boolean isRight = false;
        if(current.isLeftMostModule()) {
            isLeft = true;
        }
        if(next.isRightMostModule()) {
            isRight = true;
        }
        Module temp = current;
        current = next;
        next = temp;
        if(isLeft) {
            next.setLeftMostModule();
            current.setNonMostModule();
        }
        else if(isRight) {
            next.setNonMostModule();
            current.setRightMostModule();
        }

    }
```

There is a swap function I call which I included as well. Thank you. I am not allowed to add a setName method and can't access the name field aside from getName. I can however add helper methods to this class.

EDIT -- UPDATED the code however it still isn't working. Getting NPE on the compareToIgnoreCase and not getting the result I want.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just swap the "value" instead of the "next" / "prev" links? `temp = current.getName(); current.setName(next.getName()); next.setName(temp);` and you're done.

Comment: Sadly I'm not allowed to make a method setName() and the name field is private.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` counter in the outer for-loop is never incremented.

Comment: I updated the code with a few changes however it is still not working.